# Changing startup page of asp.net application based on the roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, global-asax, role-based-access-control

I'm developing asp.net web application i'm using multiple roles in the application, the problem is with the start up page must change based on the role. for example consider we have 3 roles role1,role2,role3, and pages like page1,page2,page3. Now, if an user is having role1 alone he must be having page 1 as start up page and if user having role1 and role2 then he must be having page 2 as start up page how can we achive it.

Comment: On the entry page, read user role and redirect accordingly.

Comment: if i do so means, when ever the session expires in application then after loging is i am not able to redirect last viewed page.

Comment: If so, you can pass the page URL where user was as query string param, and after you log him in, either redirect to start page you don't where he was, but if you know from the param, redirect to that page.